# Java - Netbeans Compile time error while no code error

Tags: java, netbeans

I have been working on a project in Netbeans and have recently moved all the classes from a single java file to individual class files.

I updated the constructors on some of the classes in the separate files, such as:

```
public class Pawn extends Piece  {
public Pawn(char color, int id, int xSpace, int ySpace) throws InterruptedException{
    this.color = color;
    this.id = id;
    this.xSpace = xSpace;
    this.ySpace = ySpace;
    this.firstMoveMax = 2;
    this.verticalMoveMax = 1;
    this.horizontalMoveMax = 0;
    this.diagonalMoveMax = 1;
    }
}
```

This Pawn class is in its own Pawn.java file. I updated the constructor call in another file as follows:

```
else if (x == 1 || x == 6){
                this.board[x][y] = new Pawn(color, IdCounter.getId(), x, y);
}
```

As you can see, the signature for the constructor matches in both the class and where the class is being instantiated. However, when I try to run the file, I get the attached error:
C:\Users\Documents\NetBeansProjects\chess\Chess\src\chess\Board.java:28: error: constructor Pawn in class Pawn cannot be applied to given types;
this.board[x][y] = new Pawn(color, IdCounter.getId(), x, y);
required: char,int
found: char,int,int,int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

The error is showing that the code is expecting the old constructor (char,int) instead of the new one (char,int,int,int).

My question is, is this a Netbeans issue, an issue since the two classes are in separate files, or is something else going on?

Comment: do a `make clean` however you can do that in netbeans

Comment: BTW `throws InterruptedException` - **why**

Comment: I first did 'make clean', which did work, then had to drop 'throws InterrupedException'. After both those editions, I looks to be working. Thanks for the help!